# How to add new line in system.assertEquals

Tags: unit-test

***How to add new Line in System.assert statement***

Actual result in UserInterface

```
 1.Client Stability Risk & Mitigation: Test Risk1 

 2.Contract Terms Risk & Mitigation: Test Risk2
```

How to add new line in system.assertEquals iun Test class

system.assertEquals(' 1. Client Stability Risk & Mitigation: Test Risk1 2. Contract Terms Risk & Mitigation: Test Risk2' ,objOpp.Top_2_Risks__c);

Error:

```
 Assertion Failed: Expected: 1. Client Stability Risk & Mitigation: Test 
  Risk1 2. Contract Terms Risk & Mitigation: Test Risk2, Actual: 1. Client 
 Stability Risk & Mitigation: Test Risk1 2. Contract Terms Risk & Mitigation: 
 Test Risk2
```

Comment: add a new line character in between: `\n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can represent a newline as `'\n'`, as in most C/Java family languages.

```
System.assertEquals(' 1. Client Stability Risk & Mitigation: Test Risk1\n2. Contract Terms Risk & Mitigation: Test Risk2', objOpp.Top_2_Risks__c);
```

Note that whitespace is significant, so you'd have to get all spaces before/after each line item exactly right for the assertion to pass

Depending on your application, it may make more sense to either `split()` the string by newlines and make assertions against component line item, or do several `System.assert(objOpp.Top_2_Risks__c.contains('TEST_STRING_HERE'))` assertions to validate its contents.